# I put a password for a zip file to hide the contents in it .i made password like a passage(more than 30 words) . Is it breakable?

Tags: encryption, passwords, node-crypto

I put a password for a zip file to hide the contents in it .  i made a password like a passage(more than 30 words) . Is it breakable ?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The password or passphrase itself matters if it may be guessed. The next thing to worry about is the encryption method, and if the latest options are used the encryption is quite safe. But see for example [How strong is WinZip's encryption?](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/80/) which says:

> The Zip 2.0 (Legacy) encryption format is supported by nearly all
>   other Zip file utilities. Password protecting a Zip file with Zip 2.0
>   encryption provides a measure of protection against a casual user who
>   does not have the password and is trying to determine the contents of
>   the files. However, the Zip 2.0 encryption format is known to be
>   relatively weak, and cannot be expected to provide protection from
>   individuals with access to specialized password recovery tools.